# Test for entry status

Tags: entries, status

I want to test for the existence of disabled entries for the logged in author in a section. So far I have this:

```
{% set profileEntryQuery = craft.entries()
    .section('profileEntry')
    .status(null) %}

{% set entries = profileEntryQuery.all() %}    

{% for entry in entries %}

  {% if currentUser.id == entry.author.id %}
```

But the status(null) checks for disabled *and* enabled entries. How can I get a positive if only disabled entries exist but not enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`status('disabled')` should do the trick for you

```
{% set entries = craft.entries()
    .section('profileEntry')
    .status('disabled')
    .all() %}
```

Comment: Thanks it kind of does what I asked but doesn't quite do what I needed

Comment: @Andrew sorry about that, what exactly do you need it do do? Not sure I follow completely...

Comment: Not your fault, I started a new question to make it more explicit https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/29556/display-notification-if-no-entries-exist-for-status-criteria-and-logged-in-user

Comment: Gotcha; Robin's answer on that question is perfect 