# Display notification if no entries exist for status criteria and logged in user

Tags: entries, status

I'm aiming to display disabled entries for a logged in user and a message if no entries with this criteria exist. I've tried two different ways without success.

**Version 1** gets all entries - live and disabled, gets those by the logged in user, and then tests for the entry status of disabled (which doesn't work).

```
{% set entries = craft.entries
    .section('profileEntry')
    .status(null)
    .all() %}

     {% for entry in entries %}

        {% if currentUser.id == entry.author.id %}

            {% if entry.status == entry.status('disabled') %}

                <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>

                {% else %}

                <p>No entries exist</p>

            {% endif %} 

        {% endif %}     


    {% endfor %}
```

**Version 2** only gets the disabled status entries, then the entries by the logged in user. Which doesn't work either.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries
    .section('profileEntry')
    .status('disabled')
    .all() %}    

{% for entry in entries %}

        {% if currentUser.id == entry.author.id %}

        <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>

        {% else %}

        <p>No entries exist</p>

        {% endif %}


{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just grab [disabled](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#status) entries from the [author](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#authorid)?

```TWIG
{% set entries = craft.entries
    .section('profileEntry')
    .status('disabled')
    .authorId(currentUser.id)
    .all() %}
```

Then you can [loop](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-else-clause) those

```twig
{% for entry in entries %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% else %}
    no entries found
{% endfor %}
```